# Getting an image to fly from location a to location b

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation

I'm not really sure where to begin with this. The sort of effect I'm looking for is what you would see at the beginning of a game of solitaire. I had a look in the jquery and jqueryui libraries to see if there was any event/effects called fly (or anything similarly named) and didn't see anything. What combo of events/effects will give me the desired outcome?

Comment: Have you looked into [jQuery animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)?

Comment: It might well be. I'll report back later after hacking around with animate and let you know if that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

For a solitaire effect I would simply:

1. Move it to the position it should go to fast, probably under a second.
2. No easing, or very little bounce ease.
3. No fade..

At least that is how I remember the beginning of solitaire. It is actually a simple effect, the thing is that it goes fast but there are lots of cards. If there were just say, one card, then you would probably not even notice it.

**jQuery `.animate`**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#boxtoanimate" ).animate({
    top: 100,  //Where it should go..
    left: 100
    }, 500 ); //How quick to animte
});
```

By the way, I'd suggest GSAP over jQuery for heavier animations if you go into it, it is better for performance and also easier to manage many animations at once. Check it out:

https://greensock.com/jump-start-js